# ActiveMQ in-memory broker not starting when tests running in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, jms, activemq-classic, spock

So I'm running an integration test/spec using configuration for an ActiveMQ in-memory broker.

SomeSpec.groovy:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(SomeApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
class SomeSpec extends Specification {
```

application.properties

```
spring.activemq.in-memory=true
spring.activemq.pooled=false
```

The in memory broker starts up and runs fine when I do `gradle test` and
also runs fine when used with `gradle bootRun` at the command line.  However when I run inside IntelliJ without explicitly having it run `gradle test` the in memory broker does not start and the tests fail.

How can I take and advantage of the nice test/spec running features in IntelliJ but still have it initialize the in memory queue properly?  I know with Grails you could run with JUnit or Grails.  Is there something similar with Spring/SpringBoot so everything starts up properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your `config` files are not refreshed under `project/out/production/config/` location.

When you run it from `cmd` line, it takes the latest `application.properties`, so every thing is fine.

But `Idea` takes the already compiled config files, and if they are not rebuilt inside `Idea` then it still loads the load configuration.

Comment: Thanks @K139!  I was changing project dependencies in build.gradle and for some reason my current IntelliJ installation does not prompt me to 'refresh' or anything.

Comment: Also just found out there is a Gradle Tools Window now that you can open and refresh.  IntelliJ used to prompt you when it detected changes in the `build.gradle` and then it would refresh for you.  Not sure why it stopped doing that.